# Playing video and showing text on hovering over image

Tags: javascript, css, hover, overlay, mp4

I am looking for a way to implement hovering over an image that triggers playing a video. When the mouse is not over the image anymore, the image (poster?) should be displayed again. There should also be text displayed over the video. Please see the example below from Loop. They have this hover effect on their case examples.
I tried multiple solutions with imageoverlay or poster image, but none of these give me a smooth transition from image to video.
See the code below.

I don't know how to add text on top of the image/video that gets this "Explore" text while hovering, as in the example from Loop: https://www.agentur-loop.com/ (hover over 'digital' to see the effect).

Edit 1: Here: agentur-loop.com/cases they have a really smooth transition on hover from image to video, and if I mouseover out the video it transitions/fades back to the (poster)image smoothly. My current state can be seen here at the very bottom here: fredericlouis.com/fredericlouis.com/admin Thanks in advance! –

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.video2').each(function(i, obj) {
    $(this).on("mouseover", hoverVideo);
    $(this).on("mouseout", hideVideo);
  });
});

function hoverVideo() {
  $(this).find(".overlayImage").hide();
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].play();
}

function hideVideo(video) {
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].currentTime = 0;
  $(this).find(".thevideo")[0].pause();
  $(this).find(".overlayImage").show();
}
```

```css
video2 {
  width: 1200px;
}

.overlayImage {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="video2">
  <img src="images/apple_vr10.png" class="overlayImage" width="600" alt="apple vr" />
  <video class="thevideo" loop muted poster="images/apple_vr10.png" onmouseout="this.pause()">
        <source src="videos/apple_vr.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Put the text and the video in a div and use relative and absolute positions to make the first appear in front of the video
2. Use CSS `:hover` to hide/display the text on hover
3. Use JS to play/pause the video as you like depending on whether the mouse is hovering or not over the video

The solution is in plain vanilla JS to help non-jQuery users but can be *easily* adapted to reduce the code by a few lines with jQuery.

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');
let video = document.querySelector('video');

div.onmouseover = () => video.play();
div.onmouseout = () => video.pause();
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
div > p {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  transition: all .5s;
}
div:hover > p {
  opacity: 0;
}
div > video {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <video
    src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/flower.webm"
    muted
  ></video>
  <p>Hover to play the video!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your quick answer. Somehow I don't get the video to play. I created a separate .js file for the jquery code, link to the jquery file in my html head and to the https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js.
Do you have any ideas why it is not playing? Thanks again.

Comment: Smells like an autoplay issue to me! https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

Comment: I managed to play the video now on hover, but is it possible to make a smooth transition to the video and the same for the transition if I mouseover out of the video. It is very abprupt at the moment.

Comment: What type of transition? Describe it precisely, please

Comment: So here: https://www.agentur-loop.com/cases  they have a really nice transition on hover from image to video, and if I go off the video with the mouse it transitions/fades back to the image smoothly. My current state can be seen here at the very bottom: http://fredericlouis.com/fredericlouis.com/admin/
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Website [agentur-loop](https://www.agentur-loop.com/) toggle multiple Images(in small time) on hovering on the text...

You can do this by adding the slide show(carousel) with transition time 0.1s (very small) for each slide;

Thanx...

Comment: You are talking about the first section, I am talking about the second section when they present their cases.